# UrlParameter.Optional not working in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using below code in layout for links:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("NewProduct", "Administrator", new { id = UrlParameter.Optional })"></a>
```

But it's not working, here is my route Config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{


    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home" , action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


}
```

This is my NewProduct Controller:

```
public ActionResult NewProduct(int id = -1)
{
NewProductModel m = new NewProductModel();
  return View(m);
}
```

What is problem in my UrlParameter.optional

Comment: no error , i want to redirect to link like this http://localhost:3891/Administrator/NewProduct/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in NewProduct controller :

```
public ActionResult NewProduct(int id = -1)
{
  NewProductModel m = new NewProductModel();
  m.Id = id;
  return View(m);
}
```

and for Link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("NewProduct", "Administrator", new { id = Model.Id})"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you using `@Url.Action` helper you should pass the actual value to parameter like this:

```
@Url.Action("NewProduct", "Administrator", new { id = 1 })
```

`UrlParameter.Optional` should be used only in RouteConfig as you see in your code.

Comment: But id value where comes from?

Comment: it comes from your logic

Comment: From model that you pass to View. It can be get from your ViewModel (`Model.Id`) or `ViewData["Id"]` or `ViewBag.Id` (`dynamic` object). You should set it somewhere in your controller

Comment: but when i in NewProduct page the Model.Id Is not working

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi becouse you should set it. If you don't set it it's empty =)